# My numeric keypad has somehow got into a "mouse emulation" mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

My numeric keypad has somehow got into a "mouse emulation" mode where the number keys just move the mouse pointer around (2 = down; 8 = up, 6 = right, etc). Anyone know how to make it work normally again? None of the other numpad keys work either

Comment: i got acer aspire 7730g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you made me fix it Stephanie. after i exit from there i entered Start on screen keyboard.
There in the options menu check box turn on numeric keypad and on the left down on this on screen keyboard fixed numlock from pointer to numbers. Thanks again Stephanie

Comment: This should not be postet as answer but as comment to Stephanie's answer. Also please accept Stephanies answer.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have turned on ["Mouse Keys"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer) by accident. Mouse keys is a basic feature of Windows that's meant to make the computer easier to use for individuals who cannot navigate with a mouse (and it's also a handy feature in the event your mouse stops working.)

If this is in fact the case, pressing `Left Alt+ Left Shift + NumLock` will toggle the feature off, or it can be turned off in the "Ease of Access" center inside the control panel:

- Open Ease of Access center by clicking the Start Button → Control Panel → Ease of Access Center
- Find "Make the Mouse Easier to Use" in the list of options and click it (you might have to scroll down)
- Uncheck "Turn on Mouse Keys"
- Press OK to apply the setting and close the window.

Comment: i did all of that, the box was unchecked

Comment: But you made me fix it Stephanie. after i exit from there i entered Start on screen keyboard. There in the options menu check box turn on numeric keypad and on the left down on this on screen keyboard fixed numlock from pointer to numbers. Thanks again Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> on the number pad worked for me.